# HP P212 RAID + Tape Library = Kernel Panic

Tags: raid, hp, tape, autoloader

I have a HP DL320e g8 v2 server running CentOS 7.1 (kernel 3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_64). The onboard B120i SmartArray was disabled, and a PCI-Express P212 SAS HBA was installed with two identical 3TB Seagate disks in RAID-0 on the internal SAS port. The system boots perfectly.

But I have a HP Tape Library (MSL 1/8 G2) with Ultrium LTO-4 driver, and I need to plug it on the external SAS port of the P212. When I plug it, the system doesn't boot. I got a Kernel Panic.

If I unplug the SAS cable of the external port, the system boots again...

Can I use both ports of P212 (internal and external) at the same time?

I need to configure something on the controller? or on the Bios?

Because of performance reasons, I can't use the onboard SmartArray controller... I need to use the P212, if it supports the two ports at the same time.

Note: P212 has read cache enabled, and write cache disable. It has 256 MB memory with no batery.

Comment: I am using an LSI SAS 9211-4i, with a Tandberg tape drive, not a library, on Ubuntu. It works out of the box. The kernel version is 3.13, but it worked with previous kernels as well. This is the HBA which is recommended or at least tested by Tandberg.

Comment: You have the system disks on the same HBA? this is my doubt: can I have the disks and the tape library (or driver) on the same HBA?

Comment: Only the tape drive is attached to the HBA.